# Why does visual studio code installation fail on nixos on wsl

Tags: nixos

After installing nixos on wsl. I want to install visual studio code on nixos.

to install nixos on wsl: https://github.com/nix-community/NixOS-WSL
and you need to run this 2 lines before `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`

```
sudo nix-channel --add  https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-23.11 nixos
sudo nix-channel --update
```

the command `nixos-rebuild` switch works. I have tested it by installing git only

I followed the instruction to install vscode: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code

/etc/nixos/configuration.nix look like that:

```
# Edit this configuration file to define what should be installed on
# your system. Help is available in the configuration.nix(5) man page, on
# https://search.nixos.org/options and in the NixOS manual (`nixos-help`).

# NixOS-WSL specific options are documented on the NixOS-WSL repository:
# https://github.com/nix-community/NixOS-WSL

{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports = [
    # include NixOS-WSL modules
    <nixos-wsl/modules>
  ];

  wsl.enable = true;
  wsl.defaultUser = "nixos";
  environment.systemPackages = [
    pkgs.git
    pkgs.vscode
  ];


  # This value determines the NixOS release from which the default
  # settings for stateful data, like file locations and database versions
  # on your system were taken. It's perfectly fine and recommended to leave
  # this value at the release version of the first install of this system.
  # Before changing this value read the documentation for this option
  # (e.g. man configuration.nix or on https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html).
  system.stateVersion = "23.05"; # Did you read the comment?
}
```

> building Nix... building the system configuration...
>
> error:
> … while calling the 'head' builtin
>
> ```
>      at /nix/store/d3qda808yhlkqwaffvq34i4ks2c5lmxc-nixos-23.11/nixos/lib/attrsets.nix:850:11:
>
>       849|         || pred here (elemAt values 1) (head values) then
>       850|           head values
>          |           ^
>       851|         else
>
>    … while evaluating the attribute 'value'
>
>      at /nix/store/d3qda808yhlkqwaffvq34i4ks2c5lmxc-nixos-23.11/nixos/lib/modules.nix:807:9:
>
>       806|     in warnDeprecation opt //
>       807|       { value = builtins.addErrorContext "while evaluating the option `${showOption loc}':" value;
>          |         ^
>       808|         inherit (res.defsFinal') highestPrio;
>
>    (stack trace truncated; use '--show-trace' to show the full trace)
>
>    error: Package ‘vscode-1.84.2’ in /nix/store/d3qda808yhlkqwaffvq34i4ks2c5lmxc-nixos-23.11/nixos/pkgs/applications/editors/vscode/vscode.nix:85
> ```
>
> has an unfree license (‘unfree’), refusing to evaluate.
>
> ```
>    a) To temporarily allow unfree packages, you can use an environment variable
>       for a single invocation of the nix tools.
>
>         $ export NIXPKGS_ALLOW_UNFREE=1
>
>       Note: When using `nix shell`, `nix build`, `nix develop`, etc with a flake,
>             then pass `--impure` in order to allow use of environment variables.
>
>    b) For `nixos-rebuild` you can set
>      { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true; }
>    in configuration.nix to override this.
>
>    Alternatively you can configure a predicate to allow specific packages:
>      { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
>          "vscode"
>        ];
>      }
>
>    c) For `nix-env`, `nix-build`, `nix-shell` or any other Nix command you can add
>      { allowUnfree = true; }
>    to ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix.
> ```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know, which is that the `vscode` package has an unfree software license, which you need to explicitly allow in order to install. It also gives you several options for how to do this:

```
b) For `nixos-rebuild` you can set
  { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true; }
in configuration.nix to override this.

Alternatively you can configure a predicate to allow specific packages:
  { nixpkgs.config.allowUnfreePredicate = pkg: builtins.elem (lib.getName pkg) [
      "vscode"
    ];
  }
```

You can choose either solution depending on how careful you like to be about unfree software, just be aware that the `{}` brackets shown are meant to represent the top-level `{}` brackets in your `configuration.nix`, so they so do not need to be copied.

Alternatively... you can simply install the [`vscodium`](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=unstable&show=vscodium&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=Vscodium) package instead, which does not contain any unfree code or trademarks (or annoying telemetry)!